# incompatible assignment of type char to type char[9]

Tags: c++

I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting this error message

```
incompatible types in assignment of `char' to `char[9]'
```

The code:

```
class CabinAssignment {
    char room[3][4][9];

public:
    CabinAssignment();
    void display();
    bool available(int floor, int row, int col);
    void assignCabin(int floor, int row, int col);
};

CabinAssignment::CabinAssignment() {
    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++) {
        room[i][0] = 'A';
        room[i][1] = 'B';
        room[i][2] = 'C';
        room[i][3] = 'D';
        room[i][4] = 'E';
        room[i][5] = 'F';
        room[i][6] = 'G';
        room[i][7] = 'H';
        room[i][8] = 'I';
        room[i][9] = 'J';
    }
}
```

Comment: lot of bugs.. study more about arrays

Comment: Maybe you just intended `char room[3][9]` ?

Answer (score 6):

You declared `room` as 3D array of `char` elements. So, in order to access the actual `char`s, you have to apply *three* indices to `room`. Get it? *Three*-dimensional array needs *three* indices for individual element access. For example, `room[i][j][k]` will give you access to the corresponding character.

But if you apply only *two* indexes to room, as in `room[i][4]`, you get 1D array as the result. So in `room[i][4] = 'E'` you are attempting to assign `'E'` to an 1D array of type `char[9]`. That just does not make sense. That's your problem.

Why are you using only two indices? What was the point of declaring `room` as a 3D array? What  were you trying to do?

Also the second size of your array is only `4`, which means that the second index must lie between `0` and `3`. Yet you are attempting to access it out of bounds, as in `room[i][9]`.

Comment: Room is a 3d array because this is a cabin booking system that has the user index a floor, row, and room they want, im trying to create a display of rooms for each floor using chars

Answer (score 1):

```
char room[3][4][9];
```

says that room is an array of 3 x

```
char[4][9];
```

which is an array of 4 x

```
char[9];
```

which is an array of 9 chars.

```
room[i][0] = 'A';
```

Is trying to assign a single char to what is actually an array of char[9];

You can use typedef to make this easier on yourself.

```
typedef char COLUMN;
typedef COLUMN ROW [9]; // A row has 9 columns
typedef ROW FLOOR [4]; // A floor has 4 rows.

char FLOOR room[3];  // this object has 3 floors of 4 rows or 9 columns
```

Or better still, you could use inline-classing.

```
#include <array>  // this lets you do std::array<type, size> but requires c++11

class CabinAssignment {
public:
    class Column {
        char m_value;
    public:
        Column(char value_ = 0) : m_value(value_) {}
        char get() const { return m_value; }
        void set(char value_) { m_value = value_; }
    };

    class Row {
        std::array<Column, 9> m_columns;
    public:
        Row() : m_columns() {}
        const Column& col(size_t colNo_) const { return m_columns[colNo_]; }
        Column& col(size_t colNo_) { return m_columns[colNo_]; }
    };

    class Floor {
        std::array<Row, 4> m_rows;
    public:
        Floor() : m_rows() {}
        const Row& row(size_t rowNo_) const { return m_rows[rowNo_]; }
        Row& row(size_t rowNo_) { return m_rows[rowNo_]; }
    };

private:
    std::array<Floor, 3> m_floors;

public:
    CabinAssignment() : m_floors() {}
    const Floor& floor(size_t floorNo_) const { return m_floors[floorNo_]; }
    Floor& floor(size_t floorNo_) { return m_floors[floorNo_]; }
};

int main() {
    CabinAssignment cab;
    cab.floor(1).row(3).col(8) = 'A';
    char whoseOnFloor2Row5Col1 = cab.floor(2).row(5).col(1).get();
}
```

There are various ways you could eliminate the "get()" at the end, I was trying to go with a single theme. Charles Bailey points out you could make Column a simpler struct

```
    struct Column { char value; }
```

And then

```
    char whoseOnFloor2Row5Col1 = cab.floor(2).row(5).col(1).value;
```

I've gotten into the habbit of prefixing my member variables with "m_", though, which would make it

```
    struct Column { char m_value; }
    char whoseOnFloor2Row5Col1 = cab.floor(2).row(5).col(1).m_value;
```

and I balked at having an m_ exposed like that, but there's no real reason not to.

If you're not able to use std::array, simply change the definition of, e.g. m_columns to

```
Column m_columns[9];
```

and so on for m_rows and m_floors, but then you will probably want to do index checks on floor(), row() and column().

Comment: I don't see any sub-classing; it's an overly complex solution ( what is `CabinAssignment::Column` adding over `char`?), and it doesn't compile for multiple reasons. I think that this is poor code to recommend to a beginner.

Comment: It didn't compile because I'd pasted the last-but-one of my edits on ideone (http://ideone.com/wQy1LC), now fixed. The subclassing is in the sub-types, which are sub-classes because they're part of CabinAssignment. It uses 3 subclasses, Row, Column, Floor, and thus provides the accessor chain "floor(n).row(n).column(n)".

Comment: As for "What does Column add over char"? Type definition, for a start. Perhaps you could simply do a "typedef char Column" and have it flow more elegantly if this is as far as the design goes, but as much as I think we both suspect this is probably just someone asking for help with their homework, can't be sure it's not someone self-learning and working on their own project, who might at some point want the far end of the definition to more than a simple char, in which case this design is ready for it. But I'll grant you that outside that case it may be over engineered.

Comment: A new type for `Column` could more succinctly be achieved with `struct Column { char value; };` but I don't think it adds any value as its only designed use is as a member of another type. "Subclass", you keep using that word; I do not think it means what you think it means. None of `CabinAssignment`, `CabinAssignment::Column`, `CabinAssignment::Row` or `CabinAssignment::Floor` are subclasses (or subtypes) of any of the others. They are not "substitutable" in any context in any meaningful way.

Comment: You're right - heck I must be tired. Changed it to "inline". Also, I thought about having a simple Column struct like that, but didn't want to introduce a Nth concept. I'll add that as an alternative.

Comment: Editied - and now (see my comments in the answer) I think that's why I'd skipped that approach the first time around, but yeah, obviously I wasn't keen on the ".get()" either.